# Practical use of Expectation of Random Variable

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, random-variables, average

I am going through concept of Random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. So for fair dice we have

$$P(X=k)=\frac{1}{6}\;,\; \forall k \in \left\{1,2,3,4,5,6\right\}$$

hence $$E\left[X\right]=\sum_{k=1}^{6}k P(X=k)=3.5$$

Since $X$ takes integers but $E\left[X\right]$ takes non integer. Practically what is the importance of Expectation?

Comment: If you roll a die $1000$ times and take the average of the results, it should be very close to $3.5$.

Comment: Rolling die $1000$ times do you mean large number of times?

Comment: Any large number of times, the average of the outcomes will approach $3.5$.